# Android SharedPreferences not accessible in Main, other activities are fine?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have some data saved to my SharedPreferences but when i try to access it in the Main of my app the SharedPreferences file is empty.  If i call the same exact code from any of my other Activities i can access the data just fine.  any ideas on what the issue could be???

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int test = prefs.getInt("PREF_DIFFICULTY", 0);
}
```

using the eclipse debugger i can see that the map backing the pref object is empty, but when i view that map from other activities it is full of data...very weird.  Here is my manifest just in case it matters.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.dawghouse.dd"
android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">

<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name=".activity.Main" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.BlockOutgoing" android:label="@string/outgoingTitle" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.BlockIncoming" android:label="@string/incomingTitle" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.TimeManager" android:label="@string/timeManagerTitle" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.Preferences" android:label="@string/preferences" />
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
</manifest>
```

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```

and see if that works better.

Answer (score 3):

I know the question was already answered correctly, but I figured that I would note for future visitors having the same problem I had: There is a sneaky little `.commit()` method that has to be tacked onto the end of any SharedPreference edit.

Answer (score 0):

With `getPreferences(mode)` you get the default preferences, are you sure you've loaded data to it? Better use `getSharedPreferences(name, mode)` with name will be a defined string constant.

Comment: Yes i know i have put data into it since i can access the data from other activities.  either way it would be a good idea to actually name my preference file so I i will prob go that route at some point, thanks for the advice.